# javascript deleting the array of elements

Tags: javascript

i am having  10 check boxes.if i click the value of the check box has to push to the array,if i unchecked the check box then the corresponding check box value has to be deleted from the array?
pls...anyone give reply for this

Answer (score 1):

Does this have to work exactly like this? It would be easier to generate an array of values from the checked checkboxes when needed.

Something like:

```
// Pass reference to a parent element of all checkboxes, for example the form
function getCheckedBoxes(parent) {
  var result = [];
  var inputs = parent.getElementsByTagName("input");
  for (var i = 0, len = inputs.length; i < len; i++) {
    var cb = inputs[i];
    if (cb.type.toLowerCase() === "checkbox" && cb.checked)
      result.push(cb.value);
  }
  return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `array.splice(index,howmany,element1,.....,elementX)`. See more about splice here: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_splice.asp .

Answer (score 0):

try javascript associative array like:

```
a['title'] = 'Mr.'; 
a["fname'] = 'Brad'; 
a['lname'] = 'Johnson'; 
delete a['title'];
```

Its simple... when user checks it adds with its id as key and when unchecks it deletes

Answer (score 0):

```
function getChecked(ename)
{
field = document.getElementsByName(ename);
var topub = new Array();
for (i = 0; i < field.length; i++)
    if(field[i].checked == true)
    {
        topub.push(field[i].id);
    }
    return topub;
}
```

Above is what i used in such cases. i keep name of all checkboxes same and then pass name to this function and it returns array. So you can replace ur array with returned one. Like :

```
var yourOldArray = new Array();<br>
yourOldArray = getChecked("name attribute of checkboxes");
```

All you need to make sure is all checkboxes have same value for their name attribute.